# Question about storing a mobile application (specifically on Android)

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I have a question about storage of 1 app game. when access Storage, they have 3 parts: App - Data-Cache. According to my understanding, App contain core part about code and anything in build, It will change when another version is updated on the store. Data is something that will arise when running the game (downloading new assets from unity bucket, …), and cache is memory speed when run app. So that means when we upload a new asset to unity bucket and the client downloads it, it will be counted in the data section, right? And if a new content is used in 2 addressable objects, will it load that asset once or load twice, thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk1Ns.png)